# Symfony CMF Sandbox mysql

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I'm trying to install Symfony CMF with mysql database. 
Can somebody tell me step after step how to do it ? 
I've already downloaded project and i'm trying to migrate to mysql from sqlite but i don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tutorial in the doc: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/editions/cmf_sandbox.html . look into the file app/config/phpcr.yml that you create in the configuration step.

Comment: thanks , that helped ;) 
You need also to enable extension intl in xampp :)

Answer (score 3):

The database is configured in app/config/parameters.yml. you will have to modify that file to use MySQL. you will then also have to reinitialize the database etc. note if you want to migrate the data from the sqlite install you should export your data to xml before you switch to mysql using app/console doctrine:phpcr:workspace:export /cms